# How to secure php -YII Weservices with session handling?

Tags: php, web-services, yii

I'd like to secure my Yii webservice for an iphone application.

Login is not mandatory to use the system,guest users can also use the system.I would like know how can i implement session handling in server side to manage and authenticate the webservice requests.Users can even login from multiple phones and they should be treated as different sessions. How can i resolve this.. Any help will be appreciated ..

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since the connection will be stateless, you can't use session to authenticate the users.
The best thing to do is to generate a user-specific token when the user authenticate himself.
The token is generated by the server and stored in the db (or a file) along with an expiration_time.

Then on all the other requests the user will send his token as a param in the request.
On the server side you'll have to check: that the token exists and has not expired.

An example of token generation:

```
    /**
    * Generate a token to authentify the user in later api calls.
    * @param string the secret needed to generate the token
    * @return string the Token
    */
    public static function generateToken($secret) {
      $str = "";
      for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {
        $str .= Token::rand_alphanumeric();
      }
      return $str . md5($str . $secret);
    }


/**
    * Generate a random alphanumeric char.
    * @return the char
    */
    private static function rand_alphanumeric()
{
  $subsets[0] = array('min' => 48, 'max' => 57); // ascii digits
  $subsets[1] = array('min' => 65, 'max' => 90); // ascii lowercase English letters
  $subsets[2] = array('min' => 97, 'max' => 122); // ascii uppercase English letters

  // random choice between lowercase, uppercase, and digits
  $s = rand(0, 2);
  $ascii_code = rand($subsets[$s]['min'], $subsets[$s]['max']);

  return chr( $ascii_code );
 }
```

And the validation:

```
    /**
* Check if the token is valid (depending on user hash).
* @param string the secret used to generate the token
* @param string the token
* @return boolean if the token is valid or not
*/
public static function validateToken($secret, $str)
{
    $rs = substr($str, 0, 8);
    return $str == $rs . md5($rs . $secret);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your app is going to be doing, you probably won't need to log the user in on the web server. For example, if you want to update a users feed (on the iPhone app) when they open the app, or change to a different view in the app, you can use a webservice with a simple encrypted key system.

For example, on the iPhone app, the user would be logged in and have some sort of session. When you make a request to a URL on the server, you would pass the users ID (as stored on the web server) as well as an encrypted value of their ID + a secret Key, eg:

```
http://mywebserver.com/webseriver/updatefeed?user_id=10&key=ccbe688c7a3e3e1ebbaec12da992ded5
```

On the server you could then $_GET the user_id, and create a md5 hash of the user_id and the secret key:

```
if (md5($_GET['user_id']."mysecretkey") == $_GET['key']){
    // valid request
}
```

With guests you could just send the user_id as 0.

Obviously this is not a robust enough solution for every scenario, but it is usually good enough for webservice type simple requests. Hope it helps